# Sync my Pull request with someone else commit some changes - Github

Tags: github, pull-request

I sent a PR and someone else made some changes so it has 3 more commits and now I need to sync that PR with my local to continue working on some changes. How could I do to sync my local with the PR. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pull request is basically just a designated branch on your fork of the repository. Update that branch (by rebasing its commits on top of those new commits) and the pull request will automatically update to show these changes.

First, you need access to the additional commits in your own fork of the project. To do so, you can add the upstream repository as an additional remote and fetch the commits from there:

```
git remote add <new-remote-name> <upstream-url.git>
git fetch <new-remote-name> <upstream-branch>
```

Then you can rebase your changes on top of the upstream changes:

```
git checkout <your-pr-branch>
git rebase <new-remote-name>/<upstream-branch>
git push <origin> <your-pr-branch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebase your branch to reflect all the merged work of others in your PR. Here is how you can do this:

Let's say `upstream` is the name of the remote repository which you have forked, and `origin` is the name of your forked repository.

```
git pull --rebase upstream master
git push origin master
```

There can be merge conflicts sometime during rebasing. In that case, check the files in which conflicts are there using:

```
git status
```

The name of the files which are in red color are the files having conflicts. Resolve the conflict manually. After resolving, add the files using:

```
git add <filename> or   //for each conflicted file
git add --all          //to add all files at once
```

Once again check the status using the `git status` command. If all the files are shown in green that means they are resolved and you can now continue your rebase. Run the below command for continuing your rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```

Once done, simply push the changes to your forked repo using:

```
git push -f origin master
```

**Note:** In case, you have not set the remote url of your upstream and origin, add them using following commands:

```
git remote add upstream <upstream-url>
git remote add origin <origin-url>
```